# Initializing a public char buffer dynamically

Tags: c++

I am a noob to C++. I have a question regarding initialization of a character buffer dynamically

```
class Pkg {
  public:
    Header t;
    char buf[LENGTH];
};
```

I am going to send the object of the class over the network.
Header class is converted to network byte order

So, I want to send it like this

```
Pkg ackpkt;

sendto(sd, &ackpkt, sizeof(ackpkt), 0,(struct sockaddr*)socket1,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
```

The LENGTH field here should be dynamically assigned each time just before I call sendto.
One way I think of doing this is by declaring LENGTH to be global.

At the receivers side, I want to receive the object in an object of the same class.i.e the data of object t should be organized in ackpktrecv.t and buffer in ackpktrecv.buf

recvfrom(sd, &ackpktrecv, sizeof ackpktrecv, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddrs, &len);

How can I receive the object with the character buffer having the same length as LENGTH
Can anybody suggest me in what way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is C++, consider use a `vector<T>` instead of a char.

```
class Pkg {
public:
  Pkg(vector<char>::size_type size) :buf(size) {
  }

  vector<char> buf;
};
```

That allows you to send data in the following way

```
Pkg ackpkt(someSize);
sendto(
  sd,  
  &(ackpkt.buf[0]), 
  actpkt.buf.size(), 
  0,
  (struct sockaddr*)socket1,
  sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)
```

Comment: Oh but I want to recv the object on the server side.
So will this work,

recvfrom(sd, &ackpkt, sizeof ackpkt, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddrs, &len);

I want the data that I sent in character buffer to reorganize into the character buffer at the receiver side's object of the same class.

Comment: @CG recieving works fine but you'll likely need to do it in chunks and then combine the packets back together.  This is really easy with a vector though as they are easily concatinated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend an RAII idiom:

- Make the constructor for Pkg take a `length` parameter, and allocate `buf` in the constructor with `new char[length]`.
- Make the destructor for Pkg do `delete[] buf`

Then every time through the loop, you simply create a new `Pkg` object with the desired length.

Comment: So, how do I reorganize the character buffer with the same length (as while sending) in an object of Pkg on the receivers side ?: